# How to get the label name of a checked input?

Tags: jquery

There is a `<div>` in which the `<input>` and its `<label>` next to it:

```
<div class="form-item">
  <input data-drupal-selector="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365-lp1ntlq5bca" type="radio" id="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365--Lp1nTLQ5bcA" name="field_entity_product_category_target_id_verf" value="365" class="input input--radio form-input form-radio">
  <label for="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365--Lp1nTLQ5bcA" class="option">Headwear</label>
</div>
```

When I wrote this part of the code like this:

```
function () {
  let formInput = $(".form-input");
  let html = "<span>";

  $.each(formInput, function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(":checked")) {
      html += $this.val();
    }
  });
  html += "</span>";
  $(".product-list-wrapper .rows-wrapper .tags-container").html(html);
  $(".rows-wrapper").show();
}
```

In this case, not **Headwear** gets into the `tags-container` container, but the value of the input itself, that is, **365**, but **Headwear** is needed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of the `label` related to the checked radio you can use `.next('label').text()` instead of `val()`.

Also note that you can simplify the code by using `map()` to build an array of the `span` elements to append:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $radio = $(".form-input:checked");
  let html = $radio.map((i, el) => `<span>${$(el).next('label').text()}</span>`).get();
  $(".product-list-wrapper .rows-wrapper .tags-container").html(html);
  $(".rows-wrapper").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item">
  <input data-drupal-selector="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365-lp1ntlq5bca" type="radio" id="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365--Lp1nTLQ5bcA" name="field_entity_product_category_target_id_verf" value="365" class="input input--radio form-input form-radio" checked>
  <label for="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365--Lp1nTLQ5bcA" class="option">Headwear</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
  <input data-drupal-selector="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365-lp1ntlq5bca" type="radio" id="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365--Lp1nTLQ5bcA" name="field_entity_product_category_target_id_verf" value="365" class="input input--radio form-input form-radio" checked>
  <label for="edit-field-entity-product-category-target-id-verf-365--Lp1nTLQ5bcA" class="option">Lorem ipsum</label>
</div>

<div class="product-list-wrapper">
  <div class="rows-wrapper">
    <div class="tags-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```